# onClick function is causes “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }” error

Tags: javascript, text-segmentation

I have a problem, I'm trying to dynamically add some html via javascript, and the html has a js function that's supposed to trigger when it's clicked, but I keep getting this error no matter what I do `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` Has anyone had this problem before? This has eluded me..

My code is :

```
<?php 
   foreach($folder_info as $show)
   {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" onclick="'.site_url().'/gallery/upload_images" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:100px;"></span><br/>'.$show['folder_name'];
    echo '</tr></table>';
   }
   ?>
```

Where am I getting Wrong? Can Anyone help me to segment the line with php and html correctly..

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `onclick="<url>"` ?

Comment: If you are getting a JS error, then **look at the JS** before you look at the PHP that generates it.

Comment: Cant help you with this issue because we do not know what does your site_url() return. Though I am guessing you need to read a bit on how to write `onclick` properties.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/  — Your HTML has errors in it. Fix them.

Comment: Why does your span  a child of a TR? Why are you not using a link?

Comment: Im not sure that would cause a JS issue though @epascarello ? Would it o.0 I mean not saying its right but its not the point here.

Comment: @Andreas, I want to go to another page through controller

Comment: Ok @Dellirium, My Site_url is returning onclick="http://localhost/example/index.php/gallery/upload_images"

Comment: @PeniyalAbraham — That doesn't look like JS. what do you expect it to do?

Comment: In that case you need to learn about the onclick property because that thing is not a javascript code. Find more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @Quentin, Intentionally not a JS, but obviously i wanted to go to a MVC Controller upon a onclick ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following, it will work, I tried in my local server. You should be careful while doing quotes[single/double], to avoid the mismatch of php and html tags.

I have modified your code with the `<a>` tags..!

```
<?php 
   foreach($folder_info as $show)
   {?>
    <table><tr>
    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/gallery/upload_images" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:100px;"></span></a><br/><?php echo $show['folder_name'];?>
    </tr></table>
   <?php }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to direct the user to a different page, you may want to use `<a>` instead of `<span>` and `href=""` instead of `onclick=""`:

```
echo '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" href="'.site_url().'/gallery/upload_images" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:100px;"></span><br/>'.$show['folder_name'].'</a>';
```

You can read more about links and see example of their usage on the [MDN page about `<a>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: my php designer says your code also has some segmentation issues

Comment: What do you mean by "segmentation issues"?

Comment: Right, I forgot to close some quotes. Corrected.